# Getting a 404 with asynchronous action (Task<ActionResult>)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous

Very simply, I've converted some synchronous login actions to asynchronous and now they're not found, getting 404.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> BetaLoginAsync()
    {            
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> BetaLoginAsync(Models.Authentication.SimpleLoginModel loginModel, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (await this.ValidateCredentialsAsync(loginModel))
            {
    ...
```

I thought I'd done all that's needed, I followed this:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

The compiler is warning me that the first action method that just returns a view isn't using the `await` keyword, so it will run synchronously.

The problem is that when I remove the `async` keyword, it then doesn't compile at all. Compiler says that the type `ViewResult` returned from the call to `View` cannot be implicitly converted to type `Task<ActionResult>`.

Now, if I make it synchronous but leave my `HttpPost` post-back login validation method *asynchronous*, then MVC routing doesn't call it when I click the submit button, instead it posts to the synchronous version that just returns the view!!

I've worked with asynchronous actions before, I don't know why I'm struggling today.

Is this a bug when there are two action methods with the same name/overloaded??

Does anyone know what's going on?

*Update 1*

Okay, so this is weird.

It works when the controller subclasses AsyncController but this is not supposed to be how it works in MVC 4+.

Should I use AsyncController at ASP.NET MVC 4?

I'm running MVC 5, or supposed to be. I haven't created an MVC 3 project for ...years.

I'll need to do some more investigating and come back.

*Update 2*

I have an answer, but no real understanding of why. I tried Chris' suggestion of removing the `Async` suffix from the actions and it worked.

The strange thing is that, as above, it works when using the 'old' `AsyncController` from MVC 3.

I guess that's just how it is now.

Comment: Can you show us the `GET` and `POST` you send to the server. Have you updated the urls you are using to include the `Async` suffix? BTW, the `Async` suffix is not required. It's just there for the demo code.

Comment: The `Async` suffix is _convention_. It should only be added if the method being called is actually performed asynchronously.

Comment: Hi Jeff, in the case of MVC 5 (using the recent `Controller` class), it seems that this convention is to be ignored; routing won't 'see' the actions with 'Async' appended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An asynchronous method must have something to *wait* on. Otherwise, it has no cue for when it's allowed to return its thread and will therefore run sync (hold on to the thread the entire time). The warning is just that: a warning. It's letting you know that you're adding overhead by making the method async but not actually doing any asynchronous work and, therefore, are just adding overhead for no reason.

The reason you got an error with removing `async` is that you're still returning a `Task<ActionResult>`. So if you want to remove async, you actually need to change the method definition to:

```
public ActionResult BetaLoginAsync()
```

Then, it will compile without error or warning.

Obviously the naming is awkward at that point, but your two method names must match up to allow the routing framework to do a postback to the same URL (without attribute routing).

However, it's actually pretty unheard of to see async controller actions named with `Async`.

It's common to follow that convention for other types of methods, because it provides a clue to the programmer that they need to await the method. However, you don't actually call controller actions methods directly, typically, which removes the benefit of the convention. It also makes traditional routing more difficult unless you like `Async` showing up in your URLs (which you shouldn't).

So, I would just remove the `Async` suffix from both methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even if I add some 'fake' waiting on `Task.Delay(1)` it doesn't work until I subclass `AsyncController`. I'm not supposed to have to do that. I'm still experimenting.

Comment: Okay, so its the `..Async` suffix that's not working with the MVC 5 `Controller` base class but does work with `AsyncController` base. The article appears to be wrong with regard to the `Async` suffix, but looking at other projects of mine, I've used this suffix before. Weird. I can't explain what's different.

Comment: I would imagine this has something to do with the method name. Unless you're actually going to `/Something/BetaLoginAsync` in your browser or setup custom route for it, you're not hitting the action from a conventional controller. `AsyncController` may have some convention where it removes the `Async` portion from the action name for the purposes of routing, though I'm just guessing on that.

Comment: From what I can tell, the tutorial is just using the `Async` suffix to distinguish the sync v. async examples. In retrospect, that was probably a poor choice on the author's part since it seems to encourage naming your actions in this manner. I don't believe that was the intention, though.

Comment: I think so, too. I think this 'feature' of the old `AsyncController` was dropped in support of just not following convention (possibly for the reasons you suggest).

Comment: I'll tweet the author and let him know.

Comment: @RickAndMSFT The author says there's no bug in his code. Though there clearly is.

Comment: It's not a bug. It's perhaps misleading, but every bit of code there will run.

Comment: @Luke, download the code and show the bug. -Chris Pratt - In retrospect, I shouldn't have used async in the sample name, but I clearly point out it's not needed.

Comment: @RickAnd-MSFT: I figured as much.

Comment: @ChrisPratt The old async controller had no other means than naming convention to differentiate between sync and async methods. It was similar to BeginInvoke/EndInvoke pattern: ActionNameAsync/ActionNameCompleted. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Chris has the right answers. When I wrote [Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4) there was no established convention for naming async action methods. The suffix is just convention and has nothing to do with async (as the document states - "Async" was appended to the method name. **Appending "Async" is not required but is the convention when writing asynchronous methods.- As Chris points out that's the convention, but not for MVC apps**)

The reason your conversion didn't work is you missed that point, and the reason using the old AsyncController works, is the old AsyncController depended on the async suffix. Look at the source code and you can see that. Also look at the source code and you can see an AsyncController just a controller now since the controller base class supports async. AsyncController was just left in the code base for backward compatibility.

Create a new MVC 5 app, add a model, create a controller and check the async box. Examine the working async code and maybe that will help you figure out what you're doing wrong. Async MVC is very common and widely used.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, Rick. I've worked out where all the confusion is. In my URL I was not appending Async, so it was not finding the action. That may sound obvious, but I expected the framework to trim-off the Async suffix, like how it trims 'Controller', since its just a convention, but also because that's how it used to work with `AsyncController` - its changed since I last used it, and that threw me. So, no there's no bug, sorry, but the fact that the URL must change is not highlighted to the reader.

Comment: @Luke Puplett - If I get time, I'll update the article, I can see how that could be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe MVC doesn't match up a sync and an async action with the same name.

That said, `BetaLoginAsync()` is fine as it stands. There is no async work to do. This is a false-positive case of that warning.

You could use `return Task.FromResult(View());` if you like. It doesn't matter.